# Casting between value types on a class using generics

Tags: c#, generics

In this section of a function (.NET 2.0):

```
public void AttachInput<T>(T input) where T : struct
{
    if (input is int)
    {
        Inputs.Add((int)input);
    }
}
```

The compiler shows the error "Cannot convert type 'T' to 'int'.
So, I used `Convert.ToInt32()` which worked - but does it box `input` to an object? Is there a better solution?  Thanks

Edit1: Taken off unnecessary stuff related to the question

Edit2: Taking a deeper look in generics, it seems to me that `Convert.ToInt32` when T is already an int does no boxing to an object and its int overload is the one being called.

If that's true, the `Convert` methods seem to me to be the best option at the moment

Comment: I'm having a tough time picturing where you'd be using this, can you give a bit more context?  It's possible that a generic method isn't the best approach here.

Comment: I'm doing a tree of operator classes, which can output values according to their inputs. Thing is, these classes may accept value or reference types, and I have another function which is "public void AttachInput(object input)", which I intended to use only for reference types.  

My intention was to discern between reference types and value types, avoiding boxing

Comment: I've updated my answer with more info regarding your theory about Convert.ToInt32 and boxing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For type safety and avoidance of boxing, your only option is a specific overload for input of type `int`:

```
public void AttachInput(int input)
{
    Inputs.Add(input);
}
```

**Update:**

The OP has updated the question with a theory:

> Taking a deeper look in generics, it
>   seems to me that Convert.ToInt32 when
>   T is already an int does no boxing to
>   an object and its int overload is the
>   one being called.

This is not right, and a simple test can demonstrate it. Suppose we write our own set of overloads just to detect which one is being called:

```
public static class OverloadTest
{
    public static void Foo(int x)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Foo(int)");
    }

    public static void Foo(bool x)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Foo(bool)");
    }

    public static void Foo(object x)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Foo(object)");
    }
}
```

Now we write a generic method to model the one in the question:

```
static void CallTheRightFoo<T>(T value) where T : struct
{
    OverloadTest.Foo(value);
}
```

The theory is that because the CLR/JIT will produce a specific version of the method for each value type, it can pick the specific overload for `int` as one is available.

So here's the test:

```
struct Test { } // in order to test a user-defined value type

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    CallTheRightFoo(1);
    CallTheRightFoo(true);
    CallTheRightFoo(new Test());
}
```

The output is:

```
Foo(object)
Foo(object)
Foo(object)
```

To relate this to `Convert.ToInt32`, from your generic code you will always be calling the overload that accepts `object`, and so the value will have been boxed and must then be unboxed inside `Convert.ToInt32` (which also has to check what type it is first).

Although to reiterate an important point behind all this: although boxing/unboxing is more expensive *compared with not doing it*, it is quite possibly of negligible cost compared with any actual work your code is doing. So I wouldn't worry too much about the cost of it until you can prove that it is a genuine burden on a realistic model of an application using your library.

Comment: Well, I guess I'll have to do that then, thanks. Sadly, it seems to me that the only use for struct constraints is to use it combined with the default keyword, but that's just a different question

Comment: Basically `struct` is not that useful in many ways, either as a constraint or for defining our own types. It has a theoretical performance advantage but the GC is so damn good that few apps actually notice any difference.

Comment: Wow, you're absolutely right. It's sad though that the only way to avoid boxing is indeed creating overloads. Thanks a lot